# Integral operator in $\mathcal{L}(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Be $X=\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ with maximum norm and $k:[0,1]\times[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function.
Let the integral operator be defined as $K:X\rightarrow X$ with...
$$Kf(t):=\int_0^1 k(t,s)f(s)ds$$

Prove that $K\in \mathcal{L}(X)$

---

My attempt:

$\mathcal{L}(X)$ is the space of all bounded, linear operators from $X\rightarrow X$, by the way.

So if I understand this question correctly, I have to show that $K$ is linear and bounded?

Proof of linear would be:

$$Kf(t) + Kg(t) = \int_0^1 k(t,s)f(s)ds + \int_0^1 k(t,s)g(s)ds = \int_0^1 k(t,s)(f(s)+g(s))ds=K(f(t)+g(t))$$

Proof of boundedness would be:

I need to show that $\exists$ $C>0:$ $\|Kf(t)\|_{\infty} \leq C\|f(t)\|_{\infty}$. Also, if $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is compact (which it is) and $k: [0,1]\times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $k$ is bounded so that $\| k(t,s)\|_{\infty}\leq M$

Then we have

$$\| Kf(t) \|_{\infty} = \| \int_0^1 k(t,s)f(s) ds \|_{\infty} \leq \int_0^1 \|k(t,s)\|_{\infty} \|f\|_{\infty} ds \leq \int_0^1 ds \, M \|f\|_{\infty} = M\|f\|_{\infty}$$

Therefore $K\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ since $K$ is linear and bounded.

Is that correct?

Comment: that looks fine

Comment: To do some nitpicking, showing that $K$ is linear is showing that $K(\lambda f + \mu g) = \lambda K(f) + \mu K(g)$ for $ f,g\in X$ and $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb R$. Apart from this details, everything looks good.

Comment: @SolubleFish Yes of course, thanks :)